# is sharding same as distributed database in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, virtualbox, distributed, sharding, database

I want to implement mongodb as a distributed database but i cannot find good tutorials for it. Whenever i searched for distributed database in mongodb, it gives me links of sharding, so i am confused if both of them are the same things?

Comment: [Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/) is the best tutorial for mongoDB.

Comment: @Glavić yes i have read that but that doesnt answers my question.

Comment: Yes, sharding can considered as partitioning the database but Mongo provides many features of distributed databases with automatic configuration and handling. users dont have to worry about synchronization, replication, reliability.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may want to use [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) or [Replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) or both of them

Comment: Actually, **sharding** a database implies that you are **sharing that database**

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, if you got a read-heavy system, you may want to use [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/). Which is 1 `primary` with at most 50 `secondaries`. The `secondaries` share the read stress while the `primary` takes care of writes. It is a auto-failover system so that when the `primary` is down, one of the `secondaries` would take the job there and becomes a new `primary`.

[Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/), however, is more flexible. All the `Shards` share write stress and read stress. That is to say, data are distributed into different `Shards`. And each shard can be consists of a `Replication` system and auto-failover works as described above.

I would choose `replication` first because it's simple and is basically enough for most scenarios. And once it's not enough, you can choose to [convert from replication to sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/).

There is also another discussion of [differences between replication and sharding](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52632/difference-between-sharding-and-replication-on-mongodb) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Just some perspective on distributed databases:**

In early nineties a lot of applications were desktop based and had a local database which contained MB/GBs of data.

Now with the advent of web based applications there can be millions of users who use and store their data, this data can run into GB/TB/PB. Storing all this data on a single server is economically expensive so there is a cluster of servers(or commodity hardware) across which data is horizontally partitioned. Sharding is another term for horizontal partitioning of data.
For example you have a Customer table which contains 100 rows, you want to shard it across 4 servers, you can pick 'key' based sharding in which customers will be distributed as follows: SHARD-1(1-25),SHARD-2(26-50),SHARD-3(51-75),SHARD-4(76-100)

Sharding can be done in 2 ways:

1. Hash based
2. Key based